# Best strategy for a Firestore database for municipalities

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

Here in Italy the land is politically divided into regions, provinces and municipalities. For example I live in the city of Varazze, whose province is Savona, in the region of Liguria.

I created a Firestore database that accepts businesses whose addresses are composed like the example up here. Nothing difficult as I use an external service which give me consistent and correct geo data. The rest of the information for the business is entered by the user.

Now I need to search into this db of businesses by region and/or province and/or municipality. To set up the UI with the filter, I absolutely need to show only regions, provinces and municipalities that have a business into the db and not all those available (FYI: Italy has 21 regions, 107 provinces and ~8000 municipalities).

Looking down the internet and here on SO, I understand that the best strategy is to create a new collection to store distinct data about the location, separated from the businesses collection, in order to enable a quicker lookup. So every time I add or edit a business I check if it's region, province and municipality exists in the "search collection" (let's name this way) and if not, add it.

But how to structure this collection?

If I use the municipality as key, I'll have a quick lookup for the municipality itself (at top will be 8000 records), but if I need to search by a region or province the result is poor because firestore does not have any way to "distinct" the results (something like `SELECT DISTINCT province FROM geocollection WHERE Region='Liguria'` if you want to visualize it in SQL) and I have to do it on a server or at worst on the client (not an option this last one).

I don't know if staring with the region and keeping the structure region -> province -> municipality is the way to go. Or going for the province, being halfway between.

Another way could be to have separate collection for regions, provinces and municipalities.

What I'm asking here is what is the best solution, in terms of performance and data complexity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A good way to go on this would be to have a collection Regions, then each Region has a Collection Provinces, and each province has a collection Municipalities.

And the documents have the name of the geografic region as ID, This will allow you to lookup by the ID on the corrisponding collections.

Comment: I'll try the subcollection way you suggested

Comment: This is indeed a good strategy, performances are good and with a straightforward logic. Thanks José